# Why can I not install ruby 1.9.3-p488 via homebrew?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I already have ruby version 2.0 but for a project, I need version 1.9.3-p448.  When I try to run the ruby build I get the following:

ruby-build: definition not found: 1.9.3-p448

You can list all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.

If the version you're looking for is not present, first try upgrading
ruby-build. If it's still missing, open a request on the ruby-build
issue tracker: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues

The highest 1.9.3 version that comes up when i run rbenv install --list is 1.9.3-p429 and I can't figure out how to do a manual install.  All of the documentation I have read only has instructions from the start but nowhere addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I uninstalled ruby build then reinstalled it and it worked.  Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [upgrade rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#upgrading). 1.9.3-p448 is available in the current version.

Comment: Thank you! My ruby-build was locked on the wrong version so I had to uninstall and reinstall it.